# Button function in svelte

Tags: javascript, mobile, web-applications, desktop-application, svelte

I just changed a few things in my code... in this one I want the button 'ENTER' to function as SAME as the input field above but don't know why is it not working:

THIS BUTTON CODE:

```
 <div class="buttonDate">
    <button on:click={newTodoTitle}>Enter</button>
</div>
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/f137b909d3e740f99a030576189091db?version=3.22.3

Answer (score 4):

In your `Todos.svelte` template, `newTodoTitle` is only a string. `on:click={newTodoTitle}` should instead call a function. In particular, it sounds like it should call your `addTodo` function. Unfortunately, `addTodo` has a check in place for the `enter` key. With a few adjustments, you should be able to get it working.

1. Create a new function called `submit` for your keydown:

```
function submit(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    addTodo();
  }
}
```

2. Have that function call a modified version of addTodo:

```
function addTodo() {
  todos = [...todos, {
    id: nextId,
    completed: false,
    title: newTodoTitle,
    date: toDoItemDate,
  }];
  nextId = nextId + 1;
  newTodoTitle = '';
  toDoItemDate = '';
}
```

3. Call Submit from your `input`

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  class="todo-input" 
  placeholder="click a to-do, select target date, and hit enter..." 
  bind:value={newTodoTitle} 
  on:keydown={submit}>
```

4. Call `addTodo` from your `button` click

```
<button on:click={addTodo}>Enter</button>
```

Here it is in a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8873cbeebb544fb598b38b3c130ad411?version=3.22.3)